# Datatables sorting

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, datatables, html-table

I have problem with sorting data using jQuery plugin Data Tables. I form table with database result and always got default sorting, sort by first column descending:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display dataTable tabela" id="tabela4">
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
        <th>Counter BW</th>
        <th>Counter Color</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<? foreach ($db_result->result() as $row):?>
   <tr class="gradeC">
      <td><?=$row->service_id;?></td>
        <td><?= $row -> counter_bw; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row -> counter_color; ?></td>
        <td><div class="<?= $row -> service_status; ?>"><?= $row -> service_status; ?></div></td>
    </tr>
 <? endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

And jQuery code:

```
$('#tabela4').dataTable({
"aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
});
```

Problem is that sorting is always default, first column descending.

Answer (score 2):

With [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) you can alter the sorting characteristics of the table at initialisation time. Using the **aaSorting** initialisation parameter, you can get the table exactly how you want to present the information. The **aaSorting** parameter is an array of arrays where the first value is the column to sort on, and the second is 'asc' or 'desc' as required 
Just try like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

For more details chek link: [Demo](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)

Comment: Yes, but it's don't work. What is initialisation time? Is way I have formed table right way?

Comment: just check the demo link you will get the complete idea

Comment: Maybe I have problem because I have several such tables on same page (I use different ID). First table have descending sort, other have ascending sort.